# Does Dynamic link get lost if it's not fetched the first time the user opens the app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Does the firebase dynamic link get stored automatically somewhere with the app data ?
Does it get lost if it's not fetched the first time the user opens the app ?
What if the user installs the app but decided to only open it after many hours ?

I am trying to integrate a referral system through Firebase Dynamic links into an android app.

In the app very first launch there is a slider (4 layouts) -> then GDPR Consent Form -> and after user consent a splash Activity Starts (Where I have the getDynamicLink method).

the only problem is if the user closes the app before getting to the splash activity where I have implemented The getDynamicLink method. the dynamic link is lost and if the user decides to open the app later the getDynamicLink method returns null.

Another scenario is : in the splash activity if there is no Internet the app shows a dialog that asks the user to check their Internet connection, Or to update the google play services if it's outdated, which will force the user to leave the app and again the link will get lost.

the solution that I come up with is to have the the referred person to enter manually the referrer UID (Users are signed in Anonymosly and the UID I mean is the one offered by firebase authentication) but this solution is not so great cause the UID is long and the users will have to type it themselves which makes the process complex.

Please is their an other way to solve the issue. or am I missing something about how Dynamic links works ... Note The referral links that users share are short links built in the app following the documentation from firebase Reward Referrals

Comment: What I noticed is that dynamic link does not even appear if you open newly installed app from a home screen / app list. It only appears if you click CONTINUE from Play Store or from Notifications bar (APP_NAME successfully installed...)